# How can I download a NBA dataset in Python?

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook

I have an open-ended project for a Data Analytics class for Python. The requirements are pretty simple: find any dataset, manipulate it (however we want), analyze it, and visualize the results. I'm well versed in Excel and SQL, but would like to do this completely in Python.

Is there a way to connect to a NBA stats database through Python? I'd like to connect to a database, pull some basic information like a single table of `Final Scores for 2014-2015 NBA Season` with some columns: home team, away team, home score, away score, record after the game, home rebounds, home points, etc.

I'd like to do this all through Python, currently using iPythonNotebook. I know I can install some third-party packages, but if there was a NBA-official one (with some documentation), that'd be great. If anyone knows anything about this, please point me to where I should go.

Comment: you can start here http://www.basketball-reference.com/ or here http://danielfrg.com/blog/2013/04/01/nba-scraping-data/